# Dropbox alternative with public folder using predictable URL scheme

Tags: api, cloud-storage

I am looking for alternatives that like dropbox, have a public folder allowing regular direct link downloads via the web. The links must use a predictable scheme (or be available programmatically via their API). Direct download via those links must be officially supported by the provider without workarounds.

In the best case scenario, these providers would allow account registration via their API, or be small enough that as an indie developer, I might have a reasonable chance of negotiating such in exchange for bringing them a reasonable amount of new business via my app. A provider with open-source ties would be even better.

As long as there is a relatively sane API I don't care about what operating systems are supported, although it would be a pleasant surprise if there were ios, android, or qt frameworks (like dropbox has). Since I don't want to get into the cloud business myself and don't expect most end users to be able to, self hosting (own-cloud, etc) solutions are not acceptable.

Comment: Did you look at [these questions](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=dropbox+alternative+answers%3A1)? Does anything fit?

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately, none of the solutions fulfilled the above requirements.